# Can an S3 bucket object be used as an HTTP API endpoint?

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I don't want information *about* the bucket(s), I want to be able to search through the bucket object (CSV/JSON) with a query string and get back a result. For example, send a request to:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/my_bucket/my_folder/my_csv.csv/querys3?index=432

I am currently attempting to this with AWS API Gateway. I know that it *is possible* to create an API Gateway that uses AWS Lambda and a get_object_content query, but I figure that this would be an unnecessary step if it is possible to simply use a bucket as a searchable HTTP endpoint. Is this assessment correct? If so, here is my issue -

I set up a test method that uses HTTP integration on AWS API Gateway and using that and one search parameter I get the following as a response:

```
Status: 200 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message> 
<RequestId>#requestid</RequestId><HostId>#hostid=</HostId>
</Error>
```

Not sure if I am getting an Access Denied message because I am querying something that cannot be queried or if I am simply doing this incorrectly.

Is it possible to use an S3 bucket object as an endpoint that I could pass query strings to?

Comment: Take a look at S3 Select which allows you to make SQL style queries against S3. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/s3-glacier-select/

Comment: @JohnHanley this is the way that I am currently doing it (via Lambda). Is this best practice?

Comment: The answer depends on your goals and your datasets. Running queries from Lambda is fine provided that the query completes prior to Lambda max execution time (300 seconds). I prefer to use Athena to query S3 data. If I need to process massive data over and over then I use Redshift.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to use an S3 bucket object as an endpoint that I could pass query strings to?

Not really, at least not directly.

AWS S3 is effectively a simple key/value storage, where the filename is a key and content is the value (ok, there are some metadata attached too). So AWS S3 may only return stored binary content or it's subset (bytes from..to), not providing any custom (REST service) logic.

you may still have a look at AWS Athena 
https://aws.amazon.com/athena/ to make the data searchable 
Indeed you may create a lambda or other services reading the data and evaluating the query over the read content,  but that's what AWS Athena does

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is possible. I created an integration request on method 'GET' of type AWS service 'S3' with a valid execution role & path & others as default. I was able to get a valid response testing from the api-gateway console. All of this was configured from the console. Configuration as described by CLI

```
CLI> aws apigateway get-integration --rest-api-id xxxxxxxxx --resource-id xxxxx --http-method ANY
{                                                                         
"type": "AWS",                                                        
"httpMethod": "GET",                                                  
"uri": "arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:s3:path/<path>",
"credentials": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxx:role/asr-s3-ec2-role",      
"passthroughBehavior": "WHEN_NO_MATCH",                               
"timeoutInMillis": 29000,                                             
"cacheNamespace": "<resource-id>",                                           
"cacheKeyParameters": [],                                             
"integrationResponses": {                                             
    "200": {                                                          
        "statusCode": "200",                                          
        "responseTemplates": {                                        
            "application/json": null                                  
        }                                                             
    }                                                                 
}                                                                     
}
```

Role looks like

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
         "Service": [
         "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
       ]
     },
    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

You will have to attach the necessary policy to this. Hope it helps.

Comment: You applied this role to your S3 bucket, or API Gateway? Much appreciated.

Comment: To the API gateway integration. Please see `credentials` in description above.

Comment: PS: This only fetches the object (GET in my example). This did not run any query.

Comment: I am essentially asking which Integration type is the most straightforward to access this functionality - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectSELECTContent.html